# Assigning IP addresses with multiple routers

Tags: router, ip, setup

I have a 3 router setup in my house, and I've managed to get everything to work properly, but I'm still not sure if I have set the IP addresses that the routers assign to the clients properly.

Right now I have:

- A router in the garage that acts as the DHCP server and has an IP adress of 192.168.1.1. This router now assigns IP addresses from 192.168.1.100 to 192.168.1.133.
- The second router (192.168.1.2) assigns IP addresses from 192.168.1.134 to 192.168.1.165.
- And finally the third router (192.168.1.3) assigns IP addresses from 192.168.1.166 to 192.168.1.199.

All 3 routers have the same SSID and are six channels apart (1, 6 and 11) so I get great singal in the entire house.

What I've seen is that the clients (my phones, tablets and laptops) were assigned 192.168.1.10 - 12 - 14 etc, although they were getting the singnal from the second and third router.

Should I keep this setup or should I set all 3 routers to assign IP addresses 192.168.1.100 to 192.168.1.199?

Comment: Since they are on the same network, one device will become the MASTER DHCP server in a broadcast scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with RedGrittyBrick. If it was my network I would do his last suggestion, have one router do the DHCP.

Turn **OFF** DHCP on the other two routers (1.2 and 1.3).

Set the main 1.1 router with DHCP

```
192.168.1.100 - 192.168.1.199
```

Leave the static IP's you have for the routers the same

```
192.168.1.1, 1.2, 1.3
```

Run a cable from LAN port of 1.1 to LAN port of 1.2 and from 1.1 LAN port to 1.3 LAN port or you could go from 1.2 to 1.3 LAN ports or any combination as long as 1.1 connects to the internet. Do not use WAN ports on 1.2 and 1.3 (unless the routers have the option of changing that port to a LAN port, which they do sometimes).

Now you will be able to freely move about the entire network with your wireless devices and they won't be getting confused about what IP address they should have.

Answer (score 0):

You must keep the DHCP ranges separate. Otherwise two PCs talking to different DHCP servers might get the same IP-address.

If your current arrangement works, I see no reason to change it.

Normally, for a small LAN, you'd have one router plus a couple of wireless extenders and have one router allocate the DHCP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

1.) Something else to keep in mind when creating DHCP ranges is the amount of device that will be connected to your SOHO network. If I only had a total of 15 devices then I would set the limit of addresses to 25 (Always have spares for clients, friends and fam). Its a rule of thumb to help lock down your system.

As for your router wireless DHCP setup, sounds like the only think you need to do is turn off the secondary DHCP servers as per @opsin @RedGrittyBrick but ensure that the primary router is still dishing out the correct gateways and DNS IP addresses. In your particular case in it would be:

```
GW:192.168.1.1 for connected devices.
```

*IP address class is the primary router. 
**NB: You can specifiy a DNS or just use the same as your GW.

2.)Secondly as your using the same IP class it wouldn't matter what IP addresses the devices were given, only what gateway address.